# How to convert kerberos user to local user in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, kerberos, dist-upgrade

I am having issues upgrading Ubuntu distribution, as my user is authenticated with kerberos. During upgrade, kerberos packages are removed and after restart I can't login anymore. I wonder, if I can convert my user to a local user before the upgrade and convert back to kerberos authentication after the `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: hm, that's probably possible, but you should rather make sure the kerberos packages don't get removed. This doesn't happen normally during an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the priority your computer is configured to give to remotely authenticated (kerberos) users vs. local users.  In many situations it makes sense for the kernel to allow locally configured users to authenticate and log in, but these kinds of configurations are shaped by company policies that might prohibit local users.

If your kernel's auth system allows local users, then you very likely can create a local user whose auth does not depend on kerberos.  Then you can log in as that user to issue the commands needed when kerberos is not available because the packages are missing (or not yet configured).

However...

- I would not try to create that local user with the same username as your kerberos user.  There is the risk of mis-authenticating when you create the user (while kerberos still works) or after the upgrade just after kerberos has been configured and activated.  If you use a different username for the local user, then you avoid that risk.  In fact, the standard Ubuntu install sets up a default user that's useful for exactly this situation.  Perhaps that user already exists on your computer and you can simply use it instead of doing the extra work of creating a user account before the upgrade and removing it afterward.
- Wouldn't it be better in the long run if you used server configuration management software to upgrade your servers?  Such software usually runs as a privileged local user (typically root), who won't have login trouble when kerberos is disabled.  And you gain speed and repeatability from the automation of a rather complex task.

Comment: It is not a server but a notebook. I am worried that after `dist-upgrade` it will be time consuming to set up kerberos again.

Comment: @SarenTasciyan my suggestions are the same for server or notebook - don't use the same username in the local config as any kerberos user.  Config management software is not used for notebooks as often as for servers, but it still automates the configuration, offering benefits in speed and consistency.